# Glide doesn´t load image url

Tags: android, android-glide

I have an object model that returns a url from a database. That url is the url of an image. When I try to load it with Glide, the image is not displayed and it does not throw any errors. I leave the code image and logcat.

[image: Code and logcat]

Comment: It take some time to first load or make sure you have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission to the AndroidManifest

Comment: I have the necessary permits and I have waited a long time.

Comment: Are u sure that you recived the url??

Comment: try with picaso or any other library just for check

Comment: I checked it in the logcat. I have opened the url received in the browser and it opens without problems.

Comment: Are you updating your view after image is downloaded?

Comment: The entire view is loaded with data from the database. Except the image. What do you mean by updating the view?

Comment: You passed to little information, and almost no code, so its all guessing.  Have you tried adding some local image first in the same block of code? If you cannot load local image, then its the not the problem with Glide, but with View not being updated.

Answer (score 1):

It take some time to first load or make sure you have added Internet permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Glide does not fire exception if there is no Internet connectivity.